# Confusion about Variadic Templates with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, variadic-templates

Does Visual C++ 2010 support variadic templates or does it not?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4763799/1444073) is stated:

> Visual C++ 2010 does not support variadic templates.

But [this forum entry](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a55a69b3-747b-46d9-adfc-9a880bc63efe/did-the-vc-2010-support-variadic-template?forum=vcgeneral) says:

> Yes, VS2010 TR1 support variable length template arguments.

And there is also [an example on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982837(v=vs.100).aspx) that is listed as for Visual C++ 2010 explicitly. However, when I try to build it with Visual C++ 2010, I get syntax error C2059 on the "`...`":

```
template<class T1, class T2, ..., class TN>
class tuple { /* ... */ };
```

What am I missing? Do I need to turn on some compiler option besides the C++11 support?

Comment: The MSDN example code above _isn't_ a variadic template. The `...` there is meant to represent "arbitrary many, but predetermined" sequence of `typename`. A C++11 variadic template declaration would look like `template <typename First, typename... Rest>`, where the variadic type parameter can only appear _once_ as the _last_ template argument. I can't comment specifically on VS2010 support though since I don't used it.

Comment: *Do I need to turn on some compiler option?* Well, variadic templates are available since c++11 , so you must compile with it enable

Comment: @Saran I see. Thanks for the clarification. This means the forum entry is wrong. Is there any way of 'bypassing' the restriction of not being allowed to use variable length templates?

Comment: @1nflktd Yes, sure, I forgot to mention that I'm already doing this of course.

Comment: @theV0ID Here's a quick example of a valid C++11 variadic template code. See if VS2010 likes it: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44dd192a0b8a9516

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to these two tables listing the features of c++11 implemented on Visual Studio compilers, variadic templates are not supported in VC10:

[msdn blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx)

> C++11 Core Language Features
>
> Variadic templates v0.9, v1.0 on VC10 ? No
>
> Variadic templates v0.9, v1.0 on VC11 ? No

[Wiki apache](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport)

> Variadic Templates only on *11.0 nov'12*